# Sticky header works in Jsfiddle but not browser

Tags: jquery, css

I am using this code:

http://jsfiddle.net/gxRC9/16/

```js
var offset = $(".sticky-header").offset();
var sticky = document.getElementById("sticky-header")

$(window).scroll(function() {

  if ($('body').scrollTop() > offset.top) {
    $('.sticky-header').addClass('fixed');
  } else {
    $('.sticky-header').removeClass('fixed');
  }


});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
.container {
  height: 2000px;
}
.cover-photo-container {
  width: 700px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
.small-box {
  width: 163px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  float: left;
}
.sticky-header {
  width: 700px;
  height: 50px;
  background: orange;
}
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="cover-photo-container">Please scroll</div>
  <div class="small-box"></div>
  <div class="small-box"></div>
  <div class="small-box"></div>
  <div class="small-box"></div>
  <div class="clear">
    <div>
      <div class="sticky-header">This needs to be fixed when hits top of screen</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To create a fixed header. It works in the jsFiddle, but not on my Safari browser. I have checked the code in the browser and it is not been overridden by anything, as there is nothing on the page apart from what you can see.

Are there any suggestions why this may be happening?

Comment: Is Safari the only browser with the problem?

Comment: @j08691 no it also happens in chrome

Comment: Looks like you meant perhaps "from my server" not "in browser"?  If that is the case, then there is something else on the page with perhaps an impact upon the issue here.

Comment: This `if ( $('body').scrollTop() > offset.top){
    $('.sticky-header').addClass('fixed');
} else {
     $('.sticky-header').removeClass('fixed');
}`  could also be `$('.sticky-header').toggleClass('fixed',( $('body').scrollTop() > offset.top));`

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss , there is nothing else on the page, that what is so frustrating

Comment: you MIGHT try adding a semicolon to `var sticky = document.getElementById("sticky-header")` Lots of people omit these however, I see sometimes where it has a negative impact or expectation to do so.Note also that `sticky` is never used and this  could be removed

Comment: @Mark I was just typing out a comment to the effect that the `sticky` variable doesn't seem to be needed at all, so the OP could just remove it. But a semicolon wouldn't hurt either :). The example works in Chrome 50 on Windows 8.1

Comment: Are you running this in Safari on Mac or iOS? I know Safari on iOS used to have issues with `position:fixed`, but I believe that was solved a long time ago.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan position:fixed works fine. It is just everything else. i will try and use a different code, as this one is giving me endless problems. thanks for all your help

Comment: The fiddle was missing closing div tags but that made no difference (fiddle worked either way)  Just in case...although it IS in the recent code added.  I don't see how the global `offset` might get overwritten but...

Comment: I tried this code in IE, Chrome, and Firefox on a windows machine. They all worked fine. Do you have more JavaScript? Could it be a collision/scope issue?

Comment: @KarlGalvez i have tried it in chrome, it doesn't sticky to the top at all. just scrolls past it

Comment: Try onDomready, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24851042/cross-browser-issue-with-jquery-offsettop-returning-different-values

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess, perhaps the window/document object in some browsers define an "offset" so we change it, try this:

```
var myoffset = $(".sticky-header").offset();
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('.sticky-header').toggleClass('fixed', ($('body').scrollTop() > myoffset.top));
});
```